# Forcing APN DNS to be used in Android

Tags: android, networking

Some specific requests in my application need to go over `MMS APN`. This is achieved by using `requestRouteToHost(TYPE_MOBILE_MMS, <specific host>)`. This usually works. 
However, when the device is connected to a private `Wi-Fi`, that has no connection to the Internet, I can't complete the preceding request, as `requestRouteToHost` required a resolved address (i.e. DNS resolved), and the Wi-Fi connection has no access to a `DNS`.

My question - is there a way for me to make sure a DNS resolve request goes through the `MMS APN` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
You simply need to call startUsingNetworkFeature BEFORE you try to resolve the host.
That way, even if you're on a Wi-Fi connection that has no Internet reachability, the device should get to a DNS.